# How to check for conflicting annotations in Hibernate Validator?

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

Let's say I am using Hibernate Validator and I write the following code:

```
@Email
@Range(min=3,max=7)
public String getSomething() {
    // ...
}
```

The `@Email` annotation works on `CharSequence` implementations (Strings, etc.) only. The `@Range` annotation works on numeric types only.

When I execute this code, nothing special happens. `getSomething()` does the same exact thing it did before I added these annotations.

How do I use Hibernate Validator to detect that I can't use these two annotations together? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you have in Java an annotation placed on some method based on it's return type? I don't think so

Comment: @Euegene - this is what Hibernate Validator does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [JavaDoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/index.html?org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Range.html) the `@Range` constraint also works for string representations of numbers. So everything is alright here from Hibernate Validator's perspective.

Note that invoking the `getSomething()` method doesn't automatically trigger an evaluation of the constraints. To validate the constraints, use the `javax.validation.Validator` API. In case of misplaced constraints (e.g. `@Email` put to a number), Hibernate Validator will throw an exception during validation (e.g. upon invocation of `Validator#validate()`.

In order to detect misplaced at compile time instead of runtime you can use the [annotation processor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-annotation-processor) provided by Hibernate Validator. This processor can be plugged into the javac compiler or your IDE and will raise a compile error if it detects illegal constraints.